# Удаление определенных символов из строки

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "agaga";
    while (a.find("a"))
    {
        a.erase(a.find("a"), 1);
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Не могу понять, почему программа выходит за рамки строки, ведь строго обозначен символ, который надо удалить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

эффективнее решить задачу можно с использованием идиомы erase-remove:

```
  std::string a = "agaga";

  a.erase(std::remove(a.begin(), a.end(), 'a'), a.end());

  std::cout << a << '\n';
```

**обьяснение:** remove смещает элементы не равные `'a'` в начало строки в том же порядке в каком они были изначально, потом возвращает итератор на первый элемент равный `'a'` (эти элементы лежат в хвосте строки), и затем erase затирает ненужные элементы от начала этого итератора и до конца

Answer (score 1):

Программа  ни за какие рамки не выходит. Она остается в рамках той программы, что вы написали:

Для данной строки `a.find("a")` вернет ноль, поскольку символ был найден под нулевым индексом( первый элемент строки), и тело цикла не выполняется...

Если хотите удалить все символы `а` из строки, то, например так:

```
for (size_t k = a.find('a'); k != a.npos;  k = a.find('a', k ))
{
    a.erase(k, 1);
}
```